# There are pointer members in the C language structure, and how to output the structure data to the serial port

Tags: c

```
    char *ssid,num;

    ssid = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    memcpy(ssid,"123456",6);

    struct stu{
    uint8_t head;
    char *name;  
    uint8_t end;

    } stu1 = {0x55, ssid,  0xf0 };



    //printf("%s",stu1.name);
    //how to output the structure data to the serial port.
    send_msg((char *)&stu1,sizeof(stu1));

    free(ssid);
```

Comment: `stu1.name` is a `char *` already, and what's the question? Yes if `send_msg` sends a message of given length then that's the way

Comment: Pointers are local to the running program. Pointers are not valid anywhere else. And you seem to be sending the *pointer* `name` over the serial line, not the data it points to.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to store indefinite data in the structure, and then sizeof the size of the structure, and send out the structure data

Comment: 谁可以实现这代码目的，可以贴出实例吗，谢谢
Who can achieve the purpose of the code, can paste an example, thank you.

Comment: Who can achieve the purpose of the code, can paste an example, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your struct contains a pointer (i.e. `name`), it makes no sense to send the whole struct to the serial port. A pointer is something local to the program that it doesn't make sense to print.

So you need to print the members one by one. Like:

```
send_msg(&stu1.head, sizeof stu1.head);
send_msg(stu1.name, 6);
send_msg(&stu1.end, sizeof stu1.end);
```

BTW....

Notice that `name` is **not** zero terminated. That means that `name` is not a string. I guess you want it to be a string. So you should do:

```
int len = strlen("123456");
ssid = malloc(len + 1);  // notice + 1 for the zero termination
memcpy(ssid,"123456", len + 1);  // or strcpy(ssid, "123456");
```

and then you can do

```
send_msg(stu1.name, strlen(stu1.name));
```

Comment: I know, I just want to see if there are any better ways to count the number of bytes if there are multiple pointer members.